# Count how many elements in the nth column in a whole file

Tags: awk

Input file:

```
A    1,2,3,4      #length($2)=4
B    1,2          #length($2)=2
C    9,8,7,6,5,4  #length($2)=6
```

Expected output:

```
12 #4+2+6
```

A method like: `awk -F '[\t,]' '{print length($2)}'` but working on the whole file.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `length($2)`? Do you mean "number of characters" (like awk does) excluding commas, or do you mean number of fields, like "number of commas + 1"? For example, your "length($2)" for `12,13` is 2 or 4?

Comment: More like "number of commas +1" so that length$2 for `12,13` is 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are no other columns with commas, this will do it:

```
awk -F, '{c+=NF} END {print c+0}' file
```

Comment: This is a short and the way it should be done using simple syntax!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps

```
awk '{s += split($2, a, ",")}; END{print s+0}' file
12
```

Comment: @Gnouc, when a file with no records is processed `print s+0` would report `0` whereas `print s` would just print a blank. I think reporting `0` is more intuitive

Answer (score 3):

If there are no other columns with commas, that resolves to counting the number of lines and commas:

```
tr -cd ',\n' < file | wc -c
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk '{split($2,a,",");s += length(a)};END{print s+0}' file
12
```

or if your number is only one digit:

```
$ awk '{gsub(",","",$2);s += length($2)};END{print s+0}' file
12
```

Comment: You may want to update your answer based on comments to the original question. Evidently OP means to count the commas and does not mean `length($2)` literally.